# objective-c : How to move from AppDelegate in Universal app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios-universal-app

I am developing a Universal app where I have

```
imageTracker_iPhone.xib
imageTracker_iPad.xib
imageTracker.h
imageTracker.m
```

I want to move from AppDelegate_iPhone to imageTracker. I am doing this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but its not working before this code I was using

```
imageTracker *vRDi = [[imageTracker alloc] initWithNibName:@"imageTracker_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:vRDi.view];
```

but it gave error **request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union**
. Even if code is like

```
[window addSubview:vRDi.view];
```

now The function is like below and its not working. I want to move from AppDeligate to imageTracker. please help

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {            

    [window addSubview:imageTracker.view];    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;    
}
```

In this case It does not move to imageTracker_iPhone because did not tell any where to move to this file, so want to know that HOw to tell that which file to move either imageTracker_iPhone or imageTracker_iPad.

Comment: could some body tell the reason of down voting.

Comment: Since it wasn't me, I can't tell you for sure but, when someone says "its not working" without describing what kind of "not working" they mean or mentions getting an error without saying what the error was, I'm tempted.  :-)

Comment: thanks Philip, now I made the question more clear.

Comment: Concerning your original error message, that could be because an app delegate doesn't usually have a view property or it could be a problem with not importing imageTracker.h into the app delegate's .m file.

Comment: imageTracker.h was also imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to set the delegate window's rootViewController to make your first controller active.  (If you create a new test app from a single controller, non-storyboard template, you can see the kind of code that's needed in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.)

Edit: Actually, it's even easier than that.  If you specify a universal app when creating a single view controller project, it creates the exact code to test which kind of device and load the matching .xib file.  (Xcode 4.2, at least.)

Answer (score 0):

your code should be something like this

```
imageTracker *vRDi;
Bool isiPhone = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone;
if(isiPhone)
  vRDi = [[imageTracker alloc] initWithNibName:@"imageTracker_iPhone";
else
  vRDi = [[imageTracker alloc] initWithNibName:@"imageTracker_iPad";
```

and make sure that your connect view outlet in both xib's and the file owner is "imageTracker" Class.